# Is it possible to omit the word "and" before the last author name in the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

Is it possible to omit the word "and" before the last author name in the bibliography?

I'll be grateful for any help, because I have no idea about where to find a solution.

I use Lyx 2.0.0 and the bibliography is prepared with JabRef 2.7.2.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This mostly depends on the bibliography style you're using; please add this information.